# Could not push--Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: git, github

I am getting this error while trying to pull or push in my repo

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/******/*****.git/': 
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused.
```

The problem is

- I am not using any proxy
- It works once in a while but usually it shows this error

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS as OS.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this error from time to time: [npm issue 10037](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10037#issuecomment-237617399) proposes (based on [GitHub IP addresses](https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist/)):

> I  put my `/etc/hosts` in github.com:

```
192.30.252.129 github.com
192.30.252.131 github.com
204.13.251.16 github.com
```

If nothing works, check if an ssh url would work ([provided you generate ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/), and register the public one to your GitHub account)

```
 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user:repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I donot know if it is the correct way but I solved my problem by keeping the following IP address in my /etc/hosts file.

**/etc/hosts**

> 199.27.74.133     raw.github.com
>   199.27.78.133     raw.github.com
>   204.13.250.4        raw.github.com
>   192.30.252.143 gist.github.com
>   4.36.66.178       gist.github.com
>   199.27.74.133     developer.github.com

Comment: That seems to be the same idea as the one I presented in my answer.