# how to fix the "Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused"

Tags: ubuntu, github

I just install the Ubuntu. And trying to clone the a Repository from the GitHub. But it again and showing the same error. "Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused"

I have already install the git tried all the commands like .Please Help ..

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Have you looked at this similar question? [Could not push--Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41196888/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: *"tried all the commands like"* ...? Like what?

Comment: Does your machine have internet access Are you able to send a ping or open a website on the browser?